# C# How to read the names of all variables parent and child class from the child class

Tags: c#

i want to list my variables(protected,public) from my class parent abstract and my class inherited.

```
abstract class Parent 
{
   public string var1 = "something";            
   public virtual GetAllVar() 
   {
      foreach(var item in AllVarOfMyClassCurrent) 
      {
         Console.Writeline(item.Name+" - ");
      }
   }            
}
    
class Child : Parent 
{
    public string var2 = "somethingAgain";
}
    
Child c = new Child();
c.GetAllVar();
```

With MethodBase my result is :
Var1 -

The result i would is :
Var1 - Var2 -

Thanks

Comment: What is inside "AllVarOfMyClassCurrent"? Where is it defined?

Comment: What is the purpose of this? Is it just for printing class properties for debugging? For serialization?

Comment: @Mohsenne AllVarOfMyClassCurrent it's what i want justly, its the method or anything to get the variables.

Comment: @JonasH yes its for serialization, in a signature principaly

Comment: Is there any reason you cannot use existing serialization libraries? Typically, things like this require a bunch of reflection, and there exist libraries that have already done the hard work.

Comment: Are you interested in field name & value, or just name?

Comment: I second Jonas in strongly advising against rolling your own serialization. There are many good and maintained projects out there and there's a lot to do wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use reflection in order to get class' fields. Something like this:

```
abstract class Parent
{
    public string var1 = "something";

    public void GetAllVar()
    {
        foreach (var item in GimmeTheFields())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.Name + " - ");
        }
    }

    private FieldInfo[] GimmeTheFields()
    {
        // necessary bingind flags to retrieve public, private, protected fields.
        var bindingFlags = BindingFlags.Instance |
               BindingFlags.NonPublic |
               BindingFlags.Public;

        // get current type's fields
        var fields = this.GetType().GetFields(bindingFlags);
        
        // Check if current type has a parent
        var baseType = this.GetType().BaseType;
        while(baseType != null)
        {
            // if so, union properties that we have access to from subtype
            // to those properties we can get from basetype
            var parentFields = baseType.GetFields(bindingFlags);
            fields = parentFields.Union(fields).ToArray();

            // now let's analyze baseType's basetype :)
            baseType = baseType.BaseType;
        }

        return fields;
    }
}

class Child : Parent
{
    public string var2 = "somethingAgain";
}

public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Child c = new Child();
    c.GetAllVar();
}
```

Output:

```
var1 -
var2 -
```

---

But do you really need this? Maybe you can use some existing serialization libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Dorin Baba

I had already see the flags, then with your answer it's perfect :

```
        private FieldInfo[] GetFields()
        {
            BindingFlags allFlags = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static;
            return this.GetType().GetFields(allFlags);
        }
```

Comment: Yea, but there is a problem with this method. If Parent's var1 is private, you won't get that property, that's why I've introduced that while loop. If var1 is private, Child doesn't even know about it's existence because it is private and is contained within Parent class :) But if var2 is private, which is a property of Child you'll get it